# Convert a string field to a number field in arcpy

Tags: python, type-conversion, arcgis, arcpy

I have a large (>1000) number of files in which there are fields containing numbers that are defined as text fields.  I need to have a fields containing these values as numbers.  I can add the new fields, but when I'm failing to populate them.

I'm using ArcGis 10.1.  Rows may have values ranging from 0-10, and including up to one decimal place, or they may be empty for a variable (actually blank, no placeholder).

Below is the python script I'm using for two of the variables (`N_CT` and `N_CFY`), and the error I get.  It looks like my problem is in how to transfer the text value into the Decimal conversion.

I'm new to scripting, so please excuse me if my description or word choices are unclear.

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env
from decimal import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = "C:\Users\OuelletteMS\Desktop\Ice_Data_testarea"

listFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")  
for fc in listFCs:
    print str("processing " + fc) # displays the file that is currently being handled

    strNCT = "N_CT"   # the current, text version of the field             
    newNCT = "NCT"    # the new, number version I want to create         
    strNCFY = "N_CFY" # the current, text version of the field           
    newNCFY = "NCFY"  # the new, number version I want to create         

    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,newNCT,"DOUBLE")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,newNCFY,"DOUBLE")

    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
    for row in cursor:
        row.setValue(newNCT, row.getValue(Decimal(strNCT)))
        row.setValue(newNCFY, row.getValue(Decimal(strNCFY)))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Error mesage:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 23, in    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\decimal.py",
>   line 548, in **new**
>       "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\decimal.py", line 3844, in _raise_error
>       raise error(explanation) InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: 'N_CT'

Comment: I realize that I did not post this to the GIS forum as I intended to do.  Is there a way to move it to that forum?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert a string value to an integer of float by using:

```
stringA = '12'
# Convert string to integer: 
int(stringA)
# Convert string to float 
float(stringA)
```

Comment: I really need to preserve the decimal, so integer is out, and float isn't very good at preserving a precise decimal value (3.3 vs 3.299999999997).  My real problem seems to be how to pass the string into the Decimal function.

Comment: Maybe you can look here:: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html 
A float() will keep all the numbers behind the point or comma.

Comment: My problem with float is not that it won't keep all the numbers after the decimal, but all the exra digits it adds.  Is there some reason I should _not_ use the Decimal function?

Comment: Decimal function is good to use. Just wanted to show you this one as well: print("%.2f" % stringA)  This one will keep only 2 decimals.